# Google Places API (Entered API key is invalid)

Tags: wordpress, google-places-api, elementor, google-cloud-console

I am having an issue where the API key I generate using Google Cloud Console is not valid. I am trying to use elementor and wordpress to add our business' Google reviews through the Google Places API. It is the first time I have used the google cloud console so I am not sure if I set up my organisation properly. It is linked to my website but not sure if it also needs to be linked to "Google My Business" or how to do that. Would greatly appreciate help troubleshooting this matter. Let me know what further details are needed. Thank you kindly.

Anthony

Comment: Your question is vague. When you describe the API as being "not valid", why is that so? What did you do exactly? What happened? All we have upon which to form an answer is what you've written. Please see here, this may help: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/get-api-key

Comment: Google's Geo APIs frequently require API keys but, please be *very* careful with these keys. They are good until deleted and, may be used by bad actors if they're able to obtain them. Please follow Google's instructions on securing API key access: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#securing_an_api_key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. I think I just needed to add my billing information even though I wasn't paying for anything to get it to work.